# Using IFileOpenDialog, with file extension filter for view/browse; how can that _also_ be applied to filter any "autosuggest" files?

Tags: file, filter, browser, mfc, file-extension

I am using a Win32 app with MFC in C++ and utilizing Forms with a series of Dialog Screens. My problem is, each of these utilizes the `IFileOpenDialog`, using `SetFileTypes()` to set the file extension filter by setting `COMDLG_FILTERSPEC`.  This has worked perfectly for years to limit the view in browser to just the root/basename of the file.

However, recently it's been discovered that the user can type in the file name `combobox` in the File Open (Explorer Style) Dialog, and the "autosuggest" lists files *regardless* of extension.  The user may then select from the auto-suggest an un-filtered file extension, which is returned as "legal" (though it should be an illegal selection).  It seems the `_FILEOPENDIALOGOPTIONS` could be used with the `FOS_STRICTFILETYPES` set, except that (according to [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_fileopendialogoptions)) only applies exclusively to "SaveDialog", and not "OpenDialog" scenarios.

Is there a simple way (some other parameter or configuration setting) to force the file extension filter to apply to the AutoSuggest as well ?  Or to limit the legal selectable/return selection to the specified file extension ?

Comment: You could register a callback using `IFileDialog::Advise()` and override `IFileDialogEvents::OnFileOk()` method to test validity of the extension of the selected file.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  A form of post-Dialog interrogation of its return is what I was assuming would have to be done. I was hoping for a solution that limits/inhibits/filters the AutoSuggest from displaying any "illegal" file ext's in the 1st place.  This route (your suggestion) creates a bad user experience: being offered a "suggested" file, choosing it, and only after File Browser close does the callback do the integrity check and give user feedback that a DIFFERENT constraint must be self-applied (manually, by the user NOT selecting from the autosuggest offerings) on the file selection.

Comment: It might be possible to customize the autocomplete functionality, though I've never tried and it won't be trivial. Autocomplete functionality is provided by the [`IAutoComplete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/ac-ovw) interface. So you could create an instance with your own custom source, which would filter filenames, as described by [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-enable-autocomplete-manually). Get the handle of the filename edit control and call `IAutoComplete::Init`, passing this handle.